# CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED by model.predict() using tensorflow2.3

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.x

I use efficient-net with tensorflow2.3 API (keras==2.4.3)
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/efficientnet

I could train and prediction on jupyterlab.
On the other hand, while Flask implementation, model checkpoint could be loaded but model.predict(numpy_img_array) doesn't work, and the following error occured. What does this error mean ?

And I used docker image `tensorflow/tensorflow:2.3.0-gpu-jupyter` is used, and I checked model.summary() works correctly.

Sincerely

```
 2020-09-04 11:22:40.559654: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:951] could not synchronize on CUDA context: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: initialization error :: *** Begin stack trace ***
   tensorflow::CurrentStackTrace()
   stream_executor::gpu::GpuDriver::SynchronizeContext(stream_executor::gpu::GpuContext*)
   stream_executor::StreamExecutor::SynchronizeAllActivity()
   tensorflow::GPUUtil::SyncAll(tensorflow::Device*)
   tensorflow::BaseGPUDevice::Sync()
   tensorflow::TensorHandle::CopyToDevice(tensorflow::EagerContext const&, tensorflow::Device*, tensorflow::Tensor*)
   tensorflow::TensorHandle::Resolve(tensorflow::Status*)
   TFE_TensorHandleResolve
   _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
   _PyFunction_FastCallDict
   _PyObject_FastCallKeywords
   _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
   PyObject_Call
   _PyFunction_FastCallDict
   _PyObject_FastCallKeywords
   _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
   PyEval_EvalCode
   PyRun_FileExFlags
   PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags
   Py_Main
   main
   __libc_start_main
   _start
 *** End stack trace ***
```

Comment: It turns out the following can't execute neither

`a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)`

Out  `F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:219] Failed setting context: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: initialization error`

Comment: which GPU are you using?

Comment: @TakehikoEsaka any solution to this?

Comment: Have you solved it? I face the same error as you.